# add Graphics to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

I just started to learn Graphics in Java.
can someone explain that what is different between super() and JFrame?
when I used super() I can draw Graphics, but I can't draw in JFrame.

```
public class Screen extends JFrame {
public JFrame fra = new JFrame();

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
BufferedImage img=null;
public void paint(Graphics g){
    try{
        img=ImageIO.read(new File("D:/strawberry.jpg"));
    }catch (IOException e){}
    try{
        g.drawImage(img, 100,100, null);
    }catch (Exception e){}
}

public Screen()
{
    /*
    super ("kingdom");
    setSize(700,700);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    */
    // normal JFrame--------------------------------------------------
    fra.setTitle("kingdom");
    fra.setSize(600,600);
    fra.setResizable(false);
    fra.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
    JMenu option = new JMenu("Option");

    JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
    JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save");
    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    JMenuItem controlkey = new JMenuItem("Control key");
    JMenuItem sound = new JMenuItem("Sound");

    fra.setJMenuBar(bar);
    bar.add(file);
    bar.add(edit);
    bar.add(option);
    file.add(open);
    file.add(save);
    file.add(exit);
    edit.add(controlkey);
    edit.add(sound);

    fra.setVisible(true);
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
}

public static void main(String[] a){
    new Screen();
}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should start by looking [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Answer (score 1):

Do the drawing in a class that extends `JPanel`, then set an instance of that class as the content pane of the frame, or add it to the content pane whatever suits you. You can also do this with a class that extends a bare `JComponent` of course.

The drawing in that class would be done in an override of [`paintComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29).